# Best practive for on a hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this simple function that when you hover over an element its child element appears. When the user leaves (`mouseout`) the child element I then hide this, I also want it to hide when the user leaves (`mouseout`) the trigger `#tweeter`. I've created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/np1cb3k0/ sorry if this isn't very clear, but hopefully you will understand my code!

```
$('#tweeter').on('mouseenter', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('ul').show();
});

$('.subicons').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: So... is something broken?

Comment: Why didn't you implement it with css?

Comment: @AnupamBasak the way he implemented it, he can't. There is a space between the button and the pop up.

Comment: Best practice would be using CSS pseudo hover where you can. On hover gets expensive if you're traversing the dom with `.find('ul')` each time. Would you like help converting to CSS?

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that there is a separation between your button and the pop up. So even if the `ul` is a child of `#tweeter`, since they are not *hugging* each other, the `mouseout` is triggered.

What i suggest you is to use a small timeout on the mouse out. A timeout that you clear on the mouse over. That will allow some time to go on the popup and prevent the `hide()`.

Something like that :

```
$('#tweeter').on({
    mouseenter : function(e){
        var $this = $(this);
        clearTimeout($this.data('_timer'));
        $(this).find('ul').show();
    },
    mouseleave : function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data('_timer', setTimeout(function(){
            $this.find('ul').hide();
        },1000))
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/np1cb3k0/7/)

Answer (score 0):

on mouseleave you target the .subicons class instead of the  "#tweeter" try this http://jsfiddle.net/np1cb3k0/5/

```
$('#tweeter').on('mouseenter', function(e){
    //console.log('OOSH');
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('ul').show();
});


$('#tweeter').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').hide();
});
```

Comment: Same problem as the first answer......Test it try to click a subicon

Comment: i actually didnt understood exactly what he is asking and what is his problem

Answer (score -1):

Your mouseleave event is attached to the subicons. It works fine after you hovered over the subicons first.