# Show a Sub List of Social Icons onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Having a nightmare ...

I have a list of social icons three social account, Twitter, Facebook, Pinterest.

However, as I have three twitter accounts I want it that when you click on the twitter icon you then see a sub menu of uls containing three li's for my other Twitter accounts.

```
    <div class="socials">
        <ul>
            <li id="tweeter">
                <a href=""><i class="icon icon-twitter">Twitter</i>
                    <ul class="subicons">
                        <li><a href="" target="_blank" class="twitter-one">a</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" target="_blank" class="twitter-two">a</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" target="_blank" class="twitter-three">a</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </a>
            </li>
        <li><a href="" target="_blank"><i class="icon icon-linkedin">Facebook</i></a></li>
        <li><a href="" target="_blank"><i class="icon icon-linkedin">Pinterest</i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS to pistion the list of three Twitter Accounts above

```
.socials ul li ul.subicons {
    position:absolute;  
    top:-55px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:152px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-57px;
    text-align:center;
}

.socials ul li ul.subicons li {display:block; margin:0 5px; width:40px; height:40px; text-indent:-9999px;}

.socials ul li ul.subicons li a.twitter-one {
    background:red;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    display:block;
}

.socials ul li ul.subicons li a.twitter-two {
    background:blue;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    display:block;
}

.socials ul li ul.subicons li a.twitter-three {
    background:yellow;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: IS just coincidence or is the exact same code here **http://stackoverflow.com/q/27567672/2887133** ... and seems like the same question

Comment: I found this as the nearest working example and based my code on it. However, this uses the mouse event and I just need it to work onclick etc )

Comment: So why don't you just change the event from hover to click? Did you know at least a little about jquery?

Comment: I don't know how to :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/np1cb3k0/8/

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I was just finding hard as it was becoming frustrating. :)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the answer on that other thread Danko pointed to, your jQuery would have to look something like this:

## Show/hide on click:

### Option 1:

```
$('#tweeter').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css( "display", $(this).css("display") === "none" ? "block" : "none" );
});
```

### Option 2:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tweeter", this).on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).find(".subicons").toggle();
    });
});
```

## Show on click, hide on blur:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".icon-twitter-1", this).on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings(".subicons").toggle();
    });
    $(".icon-twitter-2").on({
        "click": function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).siblings(".subicons").show();
        },
            "blur": function () {
                $(this).siblings(".subicons").animate({"opacity": "1"}, 500, function(){$(this).hide();});
            }
    });
});
```

### Explanation:

The blur event handler uses an animation to delay the `hide()` command, so that users can click on any of the shown Twitter links (which will trigger the blur event) before they are hidden.

## Demo:

**Notice: I changed your original html a bit.**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".icon-twitter-1", this).on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings(".subicons").toggle();
    });
    $(".icon-twitter-2").on({
        "click": function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).siblings(".subicons").show();
        },
            "blur": function () {
                $(this).siblings(".subicons").animate({"opacity": "1"}, 500, function(){$(this).hide();});
            }
    });
});
```

```css
a.trigger {
    color:#000;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.subicons
/*, div.blur:blur p.twitter */
 {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><strong>Show/hide on click:</strong></p>
<div class="socials click">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a id="tweeter" href="" class="icon icon-twitter icon-twitter-1"><i>Twitter</i></a>
            <ul class="subicons">
                <li><a href="" target="_blank" class="twitter-one">Twitter 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="" target="_blank" class="twitter-two">Twitter 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="" target="_blank" class="twitter-three">Twittee 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<p style="margin-top:30px"><strong>Show on click, hide on blur:</strong></p>
<div class="socials click">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a id="tweeter" href="" class="icon icon-twitter icon-twitter-2"><i >Twitter</i></a>
            <ul class="subicons">
                <li><a href="" target="_blank" class="twitter-one">Twitter 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="" target="_blank" class="twitter-two">Twitter 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="" target="_blank" class="twitter-three">Twittee 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, true that. Updated my answer to reflect your suggestion.